# Express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option

Tags: directus

**hi
i typed (npx directus start) and this is what it showed me :**

express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option node_modules/directus/dist/middleware/session.js:29:44
15:09:53  "KEY" Environment Variable is missing.

help pls

Comment: By the looks of it, you're missing an environment variable. But without your implementation and the full error message, it's hard to say what the problem is

Comment: i've solved it thank you

Comment: could you write the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the `.env` file or maybe it has been corrupted for some reason.
So, you just need to create it (if you have none) then add this into:

```
KEY="your-random-key-string"
SECRET="your-random-secret-string"
```

Otherwise, you can also put "env" variables directly on the command line:

```
KEY="your-random-key-string" SECRET="your-random-secret-string" npx directus start
```

---

Bonus: I had the same problem by using `docker` in a basic way (without `docker compose`) and I solved like this:

```
docker run -p 8055:8055 \
-e KEY="1B64d95c-2346-43fA-bF51-bc9993dc7a27" \
-e SECRET="sSdqSAT7mw_nFGyPsR3f1qRyzp_TjqEr" \
directus/directus
```

Comment: It worked, so thanks! However this was a bit confusing as the official instructions at https://docs.directus.io/guides/installation/docker/ say that you could simply run `run -p 8055:8055 directus/directus` and it should work...

Comment: Yep. Anyway, it seems they just fixed the problem in the new document pages: https://docs.directus.io/getting-started/installation/docker/